# SQLITE3: Find which one are the double records when importing from excel

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using python to import from Excel information to my sqlite3 database. I need to avoid the same record to be added twice, but I'd also need to know which are the records added succeffully and which are the one that were already presented in the database. This is how I'm importing with pandas:

```
   def import(self):
       file = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Excel File", "*.csv"), ("All Files","*.*")), title="Select Excel") 

  
       with open(file, "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
           conn = sqlite3.connect('database/save.db')
       double = []
       ok = []
           c = conn.cursor()
           c.execute("SELECT rowid, * FROM record")
       r = c.fetchall()

           imported = pd.read_csv(f, keep_default_na=False, sep=';')

           imported.to_sql('record', conn, if_exists='replace', index = False)

       for row in r:
       if row in imported:
               double.append(row)
           else:
               ok.append(row)

           conn.commit()

           conn.close()
```

Using the for loop I'm able to save the duplicate row to the list but not the one inserted correctly which is always empty

Thanks for the help!